# x-delivery-count not present in dead letter queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I created this queue using a java config in my spring boot app. I observed that once the message goes to the dead letter queue, the x-delivery-count header disappears. Is this the default behavior?

```
    @Bean
    public Queue initialCheckoutQueue(CheckoutConfig checkoutConfig) {
        Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<>();
        arguments.put("x-queue-type", "quorum");
        arguments.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "initial-checkout-dead-letter-exchange");
        arguments.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", "initial.checkout.dead.letter");
        arguments.put("x-delivery-limit", checkoutConfig.getDeliveryLimit());

        return new Queue("altpay-initial-checkout-queue", true,false,false,arguments);

    }
```

Comment: Which version do u use? 
AFAI searched, at least on documents there is no such thing as disappearance:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html

Comment: I use 3.12.1 version

Comment: How did you confirm the x-delivery-count was originally set?